# How to inspect file uplods with Laravel debugbar?

Tags: javascript, laravel, axios

I am using axios to submit a form that includes file uploads:

```
let data = new FormData();
data.set('Kids', 3);
data.append('myImage', this.upload);

axios({
    method: requestType,
    url: url,
    data: data,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
});
```

This works fine.

I also use Laravel Debugbar to inspect my ajax requests. In the debugbar, `Kids` is shown in `request_request` but `myImage` is missing. I can't find it in the debugbar under "Request".

[image]

How can I inspect file uploads with Laravel debugbar?